# Convergence in distribution of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(Y_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of independent random variables with $$P(Y_k = \pm 1) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{k^2}\right), \quad P(Y_k = \pm(k+1)) = \frac{1}{2k^2}, k\in \mathbb N$$
Let moreover $Z \sim \mathcal N_{0,1}$ and $T_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$. Prove that $T_n \to Z$ in distribution.

Attempt: The first thing that comes to ones mind is of course the central limit theorem, but we can't use it here since the variables aren't identically distributed. The Borel Cantelli Lemma was another thing I considered, but don't know how to define my sets. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Uh is it $T_n$ going to $Z$ or $Y_n$? ($Y_n$ seems to go to the r.v. that is -1 w.p. 1/2, 1 w.p. 1/2 in probability (and thus in distribution))

Comment: Edited my mistake

Comment: Is Z a discrete or continuous random variable?

Comment: Have you heard of Lindeberg-Feller theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition

Comment: Z is Standard normally distributed. Sadly I have not heard about that theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_k = 1$ if $Y_k>0$ and let $X_k = -1$ if $Y_k<0$.  Then the CLT tells you about the limiting distribution of $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k/\sqrt n$, and Borel Cantelli tells you that $S_n-T_n\to 0$ a.s.  So Slutsky's theorem finishes the job.

Comment: Is Slutsky's theorem hard to prove?

Comment: It depends on what you know already.  The wikipedia article  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem refers you to the continuous mapping theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem ) which refers you to the portmanteau theorem.  If you know the latter 2, the first is a cinch.

Comment: Don't know the latter ones, I actually don't really have much more to use than Borel Cantelli and the CLT. But thanks for your help, I'll try to finish the  proof.

Comment: Well, hang in there, then.  The Lindeberg-Feller theorem a previous commenter mentioned should be on your shopping list, too. (It's the experts' form of the CLT.)

Comment: I'll check that out. Thanks :)